# Dictionary overwrite

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I want to create a dictionary to count up pressed button text type (number or string).

I wrote some code as,

```
NSNumber *existingCount = [self.counts objectForKey:(anObject)];
[self.counts setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[existingCount  
integerValue]+1]forKey:anObject];
```

Every time I push a button, it adds +1 to counter. But in this case I use `anObject` as key.

Question is when I push same button twice, does it overwrite old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say: "If aKey already exists in the dictionary anObject takes its place."
In your case, `anObject` is your key, and an `NSNumber` object is its value. Since the key remains the same, the value will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

> If aKey already exists in the dictionary anObject takes its place.

yes your object value will be overwrite